# How to do SQL IN like query in hibernate search

Tags: filter, hibernate-search

A simulating scenario is:

Search for books whose content contains "success" AND author is in a list of passed names(could be thousands of).

I looked into filter:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter

Seams like hibernate search has no native support of this.

What is recommended approach for this problem? I think I am not alone.

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post my current solution.

Get the search results with minimal projections for the keywords, and loop through the results to get only matching ones from the IN list.

I am not using filter.

Open to other alternatives once convinced.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/queryparsersyntax.html (at the end "Field Grouping"), you can write a query with something like :

`content:success AND author:("firstname" "secondname" "thirdname" ...)`