# Hibernate Search: Getting the functionality of the SQL IN operator

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Is it possible to get the functionality of the SQL IN operator when creating queries in Hibernate search?

For example, I have these two simple classes (constructors, getters and setters are omitted):

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Product {
    private long id;
    @Field
    private String title;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Category category;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    private long id;
    @Field
    private String name;
}
```

Currently I have the following query, which searches products by title:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
        .keyword()
        .onField("title")
        .matching(queryString)
        .createQuery();
```

But I'd like to search products by title only in specific categories. Having a list of categories' ids (or names) to search in, how can I create such query?

I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568055/how-to-do-sql-in-like-query-in-hibernate-search), but the author hasn't found a proper solution. Maybe now such functionality already exists?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, index the id of categories:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Product {
    private long id;
    @Field
    private String title;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Category category;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Field // Added this
    private long id;
    @Field
    private String name;
}
```

Then, make sure to reindex your data, for example with the [mass indexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer).

Then, change your query code as explained below.

You will first need the "SQL IN", which is expressed in the Lucene world as `category.id = <first> OR category.id = <second> OR ...`. Only boolean operators are bit different that what you may be used to ([see here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries)); in your case, you want "at least one" clause to match, so you'll have to use the `should` operator:

```
List<Long> categoryIds = ...; // Provided by the user
BooleanJunction<?> categoryIdJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
for ( categoryId : categoryIds ) {
    categoryIdJunction.should(
        queryBuilder
            .keyword()
            .onField("category.id")
            .matching(categoryId)
            .createQuery();
    );
}
org.apache.lucene.search.Query categoryIdQuery = categoryIdJunction.createQuery();
```

Finally you will need to combine that query with your other query on the title. To that end, use another boolean junction, this time with the `must` operator (all clauses must match):

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query titleQuery = queryBuilder
        .keyword()
        .onField("title")
        .matching(queryString)
        .createQuery();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
        .must( categoryIdQuery )
        .must( titleQuery )
        .createQuery();
```